# How do I configure two virtualhosts in nginx to work nicely

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have two requirements:

1. <*anything_except_foo*>.mydomain.com needs to redirect to https => https://*.mydomain.com
2. foo.mydomain.com needs to work seperately

So I have one subdomain that should NOT redirect.

This is what I have tried without succes, I read that using the if clause is advised against nowadays, so I am trying to understand how to do it without, thanks for any tips

```
http {
    # other stuff

    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://*.mydomain.com;
        server_name *.mydomain.com
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name foo.mydomain.com
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the "\*" works, what do you expect to happen when you redirect to https://*.mydomain.com ?

Comment: He's expecting a wildcard subdomain SSL redirect - don't know if that part would work myself either

Answer (score 1):

Nginx still recommends using IF's for rewrites only:

Here's what they wanted to do:

> disable non-rewrite directives inside if completely

It's only when you're on the location part where 'if is evil' - here's the full reading, and why they want to disable it's action everywhere else (apart from where you're using it)

http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Go for it, save yourself a massive headache :)